# How to refuse period in android EditText

Tags: android

sorry my english, I want to refuse `keyup` when user type *.* (KEYCODE_PERIOD) in `EditText`.

Here is my code;

```
<EditText 
     android:id="@+id/input"
     android:digits=".0123456789" 
     android:inputType="number" 
/>
```

and

```
input.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

anything can not be pressed but the *period*. why?

Comment: you do not want to pop up keypad . right?

Comment: Do you want to hide keypad if user enters the period?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using a soft keyboard on a newer Android version, then the following blurb from [the KeyEvent reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) likely explains the reason you're not getting your expected key events.

"As soft input methods can use multiple and inventive ways of inputting text, **there is no guarantee that any key press on a soft keyboard will generate a key event**: this is left to the IME's discretion, and in fact sending such events is discouraged. You should never rely on receiving KeyEvents for any key on a soft input method. In particular, **the default software keyboard will never send any key event to any application targetting Jelly Bean or later**, and will only send events for some presses of the delete and return keys to applications targetting Ice Cream Sandwich or earlier. Be aware that other software input methods may never send key events regardless of the version. Consider using editor actions like IME_ACTION_DONE if you need specific interaction with the software keyboard, as it gives more visibility to the user as to how your application will react to key presses."

Answer (score 1):

You should implement [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to detect user input and then compare the text on `afterTextChanged()` listener. Like below:

```
input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        if (input.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("period")) {
            // do something
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I knew that but i want to know why OnKey listener can not capture when tap period?